# bootstrap spans not floating in ie8

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

may be someone can help. I have the following html. It is supposed to displayed div1 and div 2 next to each other. However it is not happening in IE8. Am I missing something ?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span3">content here</div>
  <div class="span9">content here</div>
</div>
```

I have normalize.css and bootstrap.css included in the head section of my page. FF and chrome display the div properly.

this is the css

```
.row-fluid .span3 {
    width: 20.8333%;
}

.row-fluid .span9 {
    width: 79.1667%;
}

.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can float them .
Use a float:left style on the left div

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div style="float:left" class="span3">content here</div>
  <div class="span9">content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the class span has a float property.

Comment: Ok. Can you post your css classes as well

Comment: Looks like the issue is that both spans get a width of 100% which causes a wrap. Change the width inside .row-fluid [class*="span"] to 50%